# Is it possible to define a string in Flutter *.arb file that should not be translatable?

Tags: flutter, flutter-localizations

In the Android strings.xml file this can be done using translatable attribute:

```
<string name="inches" translatable="false">in</string>
```

I could not find any solution for this for the Flutter localization *.arb files.